# What do terminal commands such as -v, -i, -f mean when you have them in a command?

Tags: shell, terminal

This might be a generic question, but what do commands like -v, -f, -i mean when you have them in a command that is posted in the terminal? Where can I look up the command meaning?

Example commands would be:

```
python file.py -v
sudo dpkg -i path/file
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are simply the program arguments of the program or subprogram. You are able to find the information about these arguments in the help messages of the program.
For example, you can find `apt-get install` help message via simply typing `apt-get install` in the command line, or typing `apt-get install --help`. For unix commands, most have manuals and you can read them via `man <command>`.

Comment: BTW, `sudo` is used to run command as the root in linux-like systems.

Comment: I was aware of the majority of the command meanings, but I was always left scratching my head when in regards to the arguments. Thank you, it is of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question myself.

[This article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-unix-for/0596004702/ch01s02.html) describes them as **options that modify unix commands**, or in other words, **command-line options**. I found this to be helpful:

> "Options modify the way in which a command works. Options are often >single letters prefixed with a dash (-, also called “hyphen” or “minus”) >and set off by any number of spaces or tabs. Multiple options in one >command line can be set off individually (such as -a -b). In some cases, >you can combine them after a single dash (such as -ab), but most >commands’ documentation doesn’t tell you whether this will work; you’ll >have to try it.
>
> Some commands also have options made from complete words or phrases and >starting with two dashes, such as --delete or --confirm-delete. When you >enter a command line, you can use this option style, the single-letter >options (which each start with a single dash), or both."

Some [common command line options](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/standard-options.html) such as -v, -f. For example, -v reference version or verbose, -f is file or force.

[Another good site here](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html).

[MacOS Terminal(Command-line Tips and Tricks)](https://wilsonmar.github.io/mac-osx-terminal/)

As far as I can tell, which ones are available and what function they perform depends on what operating system is being used (Windows, MacOS, Linux) and potentially the shell your command line/terminal uses.

**Side Note** - [Helpful Terminal Commands](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/16-terminal-commands-every-user-should-know/)